# How to use fields/tables of MB51 Tcode in an ABAP report

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I want to write a report which calculate the sum of quantities of goods collected in a selected date.

I need to know how to find tables related for the Transaction Code `MB51` and how to use them for the last purpose.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to know which database tables are used by an SAP transaction, then there are several things you can do (in the order I usually attempt when confronted with this problem):

- Use the F1 help:

  - Start the program and navigate to a dynpro with a field which contains (or allows to enter) the information you are interested in.
  - Place the cursor in that field
  - Press F1 to open the help window for that field
  - Click the "Technical Information" icon ( hammer and wrench).
  - When you are lucky, it's "Table Category: Transparent Table". Then you know which field of which database table this is. When you are out of luck, it's of type "Structure". That means that value is procedurally generated and you have to do further research where that data comes from originally.
- Activate a DB access trace with transaction ST01. Request the data you are interested in. Stop the trace in ST01 and look at the list of logged database requests.
- Activate debugging by writing `/h` in the command field, request the information and when you are in the debugger set a break-point for the ABAP statement `SELECT`.
- Look at the sourcecode of the program and find out how the program works internally.

When you do that with the transaction MB51, you will see that the tables you are looking for are most likely `MKPF` (Header: Material Document) and `MSEG` (Document Segment: Material).

Comment: Also, you can use MARA, and MAKT for material description, maybe MARC for some additional data on the material.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way which I used to do to get the related tables.

Using the F1 Help, you will also be able to identify the package name which is related to the transaction MB51.

Then you can open the same Package and there you can see how many tables are related to this package (You can do this in Repository Browser easily).

I am a certified SAP ABAP Consultant.